# How to migrate from sql server 2008 to 2012?

Tags: sql-server, database

I am facing an issue of migrating from 2008 sql server to 2012 sql server.

I am seeing two methods of migration in-house and parallel ones which one is better and how to do?

Comment: Can you give some more specifics on this, i.e. how many databases. what do you mean by in-house? what are the requirements can you move database or groups of databases at a time or are you looking to migrate everything?

Comment: I am planning to migrate all dbs in the current server to 2012 without down time.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to migrate to PostgreSQL.:) otherwise, i guess always better to make pure sql dump (in sql server management studio chose command in context menu Generate scripts, where choose structure and data) and simply execute it on new database